# Disable SlidingMenu open on click

Tags: android, slidingmenu

Recently I implemented the sliding menu library. It is working fine but the problem is by default, the secondary menu(the layout on right),if not open, slides in when its clicked.

What I want is that the click event should be passed on to its children so that the views inside the secondary menu can get click. The user can use swipe gesture to open the secondary menu.

All the answers I've looked at, are meant to disable [swipe gesture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19253440/jfeinstein10-slidingmenu-how-to-stop-sliding-menu) on the secondary menu and not the click. So, it will be helpful if someone can provide some suggestions :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update the library to update the default behavior of Sliding menu.

You would have to go into `CustomViewAbove` class and change the `onInterceptTouchEvent` method.

Remove `mQuickReturn = true;` in `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:`